# Sign Eclipse application in Android Studio with new key?

Tags: android, signing

This must sound like a dumb question but I can't find any info about it. If I generate a new certificate in Android Studio from a migrated project from Eclipse will my users have issues?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If app published at Google Play or other market, then answer - "Yes, you have the problem. You won't be able to update it anymore there with new sign."

From [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

You need to use same key as at Eclipse version.

See [Signing Your App in Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio) to understand how sign at Android Studio.

Comment: So what is the solution if I started using Android Studio after my app is published?  Just keep using Eclipse for this app?

Comment: No, keystore is a file you can use it at Android Studio, too

Comment: p.s. I still have the old key but it wasn't working in Android Studio.

Comment: I'm receiving error Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Failed to read key from keystore

Comment: Thank you, I had copied the cert from Dropbox and I was receiving error that file was tampered with. Then I re-copied it and it's working now.  Thank you for your time!